# How to split up yii2 controller

Tags: yii2

Im using yii2 and php presentation to create powerpoint files.

The point is...

I have a ExportController that has data intructions to make data useful for phppresentation. But it also has grafic instructions to create files and download them.

So ExportController is huge bunch of lines because grafic intructions take a lot of code lines.

What I want to do is to split up grafic instructions from data instructions.

How can I send data from actionConsultar (it is ExportController) to actionGenerar (Im planning it to be in GraficsController).

If you know a better way to do this feel free to comment, all suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The right way  is  create a proper `model` and add common function to this model  so you ca refer to the function in all the action of your controller passing simply the param data .. when you create and manipulate the model ..

A second useful way is based on a collection of helper function located   in a common helper class.

You can define a proper area and assign the right namespace to you eg: `GraphicHelper.php`  containing a `class GrapichsHelper`  with the funcion you need so you can import this function simply adding a `use GraficsHelper;`  when you need some function